# Setting user's timezone on session using devise in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, timezone

I have made a hidden field on login form which contain user timezone and now i want to set it on that user session. I'm using devise for authentication. When using `params[:hiddenfieldname]`  values are not accessible in the controller where I'm redirecting the user to home page. Please tell me what are the steps I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's enough information in the question to provide a definitive answer; if not, please post the code you have that isn't working.  Here's my guess...

When you log in (or out) using Devise, these actions are managed by the Devise::SessionController.  After logging a user in, part of that controller redirects the user to a location (home, by default), at which point the `params` array is cleared.

You'll want to override the relevant methods of that controller in your code so that you can capture the value of the timezone in `params` into the session before the rest of the Devise login process runs.  Something like

```
class DeviseCustom::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    session[:user_timezone] = params[:hiddenfieldname]
    super
  end
end
```

This code would live in `apps/controllers/devise_custom/session_controller.rb` in your project.

EDIT:
You'll also need to update the `routes.rb` to specify your custom path for the new controller, like so

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {
  :sessions => "devise_custom/sessions",
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i want but the issue is that when i tried this puts "Testing>>> "+params[:usertimezone] nothing is shown on my console. I have created the folder and pasted all the code you have written.Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: `puts` will not work -- in fact, the controller methods and params values are automatically logged for you in the `logs/development.log` file, so just look at whatever controller and method is executing (it may be some other controller than `SessionsController`) and you'll see if your variable is present.  To double-check that it is getting set properly, you could add the line `logger.debug "session[:user_timezone] set to #{session[:user_timezone]}`.

Comment: One issues  was to rename session_controller to sessions_controller  and i had to specify it in routes. Btw thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to mention that little detail (and will update my answer).  I highly recommend you take a good chunk of time to read through the Devise wiki, and maybe sign up for their [Devise Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/plataformatec-devise).  It's a great bit of software, but it is quite complex in certain aspects.